# Storybook error Injector has already been destroyed error when opening story for second time

Tags: angular, storybook, ngx-formly

#### Describe the bug

When any story is opened for first time is displayed correctly but when I open other story and return to one which was already opened I get error. How to solve this issue?

```
ERROR Error: NG0205: Injector has already been destroyed.
    at R3Injector.assertNotDestroyed (core.mjs:7986:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7893:1)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12088:1)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3217:1)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3262:1)
    at NodeInjector.get (core.mjs:3527:1)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.mjs:21300:1)
    at FormlyConfig.resolveFieldTypeRef (ngx-formly-core.mjs:411:1)
    at FormlyConfig.getMergedField (ngx-formly-core.mjs:390:1)
    at CoreExtension.initFieldOptions (ngx-formly-core.mjs:2111:1)
```

I have found that some similar issues were solved by angularLegacyRendering: true in preview.js but it does not work for my issue

[image]

#### To Reproduce

https://stackblitz.com/edit/storybook-angular-inline-story-controls-reproduct-w8zp7h

#### System

```bash
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.21.0",
    "@here/maps-api-for-javascript": "1.37.2",
    "@ngx-formly/bootstrap": "^6.1.1",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^6.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
    "country-list-js": "^3.1.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "simple-element-resize-detector": "^1.3.0",
    "storybook": "^6.5.16",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@types/country-list-js": "^3.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/simple-element-resize-detector": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.1.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^15.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.4",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
```

#### Additional info

I have created issue in storybook repo but there is not a lot of activity there
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21738